# Set firebase realtime db permissions to use from server

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm using firebase's realtime database to write some data from a nodejs server I have but I'm struggling to figure out what the permissions object should be. Right now it's set as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The server communicates with firebase using the npm library and initializes the app:

```
var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
```

What do I need to change to allow only my server to be able to write data? I tried `false` and `auth != null` but they both don't work (permission denied).

Comment: Are you using the Admin SDK?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, and how you are running it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase **admin SDK** you don't need to set any rules because you have **admin privileges**. But if you use node.js as your **app** you must set the rules depending on your needs. A usual case for firebase rules is to check that a user (from firebase auth) can see and change only his data.

If you want a quick intro into firebase rules i recommend this [tutorial](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/) (the tutorial is for firestore rules, not the realtime database).

The official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) for the realtime database security rules.